# fzf function and key binding for searching through environment bash variables

Tags: bash

After inspecting [`fzf/shell/key-bindings.bash`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/shell/key-bindings.bash) I came up with the following, to be put in my `~/.bashrc`:

```bash
fzf_get_env_vars() {
  local cmd opts selected
  cmd='command env | command sed "s/=.*//;s/^/$/"'
  opts="--height ${FZF_TMUX_HEIGHT:-40%} --bind=ctrl-z:ignore --reverse $FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS $FZF_CTRL_T_OPTS -m"
  selected="$(eval "$cmd" \
    | FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS="$opts" $(__fzfcmd) "$@" \
    | while read -r item; do
      printf '%s ' "$item"
    done
  )"
  READLINE_LINE="${READLINE_LINE:0:$READLINE_POINT}$selected${READLINE_LINE:$READLINE_POINT}"
  READLINE_POINT=$(( READLINE_POINT + ${#selected} ))
}

# I'm a vi-mode user, so no need for emacs mapping
bind -m vi-command -x '"\ee": fzf_get_env_vars'
bind -m vi-insert -x '"\ee": fzf_get_env_vars'
```

Major changes I've applied to what I've seen in the linked files are

- I've not split the function that calls `fzf` and retrieves the user-selected values from the function reassinging `READLINE_LINE` and `READLINE_POINT`;
- given the inputs are variable names, I think not escaping (i.e. `'%s '` instead of `'%q '`) is safe,
- which in turns also allows me to prepend `$` (via the second `s` command in the `sed` script) without it being escaped.

[ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) detects no issues with the code.

Answer (score 3):

It's worth avoiding `eval` if possible.

Given your code, without the `eval` I came up with this:

```bash
fzf_sed_env_vars_cmd() {
  builtin command env |
  builtin command awk -F'=' '{printf "$%s\n", $1}'
  # builtin command sed "s/=.*//;s/^/$/"'
}

fzf_get_env_vars() {
  builtin local opts selected

  opts="--height ${FZF_TMUX_HEIGHT:-40%} --bind=ctrl-z:ignore --reverse $FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS $FZF_CTRL_T_OPTS -m"
  selected="$( ##: Look Mah, No Eval!!! :-)
      fzf_sed_env_vars_cmd |
      FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS="$opts" $(__fzfcmd) "$@" |
      while builtin read -r item; do
        builtin printf '%s ' "$item"
      done
  )"
  READLINE_LINE="${READLINE_LINE:0:$READLINE_POINT}$selected${READLINE_LINE:$READLINE_POINT}"
  READLINE_POINT=$(( READLINE_POINT + ${#selected} ))
}

# I'm a vi-mode user, so no need for emacs mapping
builtin bind -m vi-command -x '"\ee": fzf_get_env_vars'
builtin bind -m vi-insert -x '"\ee": fzf_get_env_vars'
```

---